# How do I implement an optional redirect on a ASP MVC ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ActionResult method for which I want to redirect to two other Action methods but this will depend on the value of a certain variable that is being passed in. When I attempt to run the action method it is not redirecting according to the logic but rather the else portion of the loop always.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PushBatch(FormCollection formcollection)
{
    ......
    ......
    NewCodesCount();
    int count = NewCodesCount();

    if (count > 1)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ActionRequired");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("BatchProcessing");
    }
}
```

When the code above runs it is always redirecting to the BatchProcessing action method even when the value of count is greater than 1.

What am I missing and why is the logic skipping the If part of the loop ?

Comment: Would it possibly be because you're calling `NewCodesCount` twice? What does `NewCodesCount` do and look like? `depend on the value of a certain variable that is being passed in` what variable? To test and make sure you can redirect to `ActionRequired`, comment out everything and just return `return RedirectToAction("ActionRequired");` does that work? Also `If part of the loop`, isn't a loop, it's a statement to run based on the value of a Boolean expression (in your case `count > 1`).

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the `if(count>1)` to 100% confirm what you are saying?

Comment: Yes I have just done that and the value of count is the same as  in line int count = NewCodesCount();

Comment: I have removed NewCodesCount its no longer calling twice still its autoredirecting to the else part